# Class equality with coercion

Tags: ruby, equality

I created this class based on predefined tests

```
class Roman
  include Comparable
  ROMAN_NUMBERS = { 1000 => "m", 900 => "cm", 500 => "d", 400 => "cd", 
      100 => "c", 90 => "xc", 50 => "l", 40 => "xl", 10 => "x", 9 => "ix", 
      5 => "v", 4 => "iv", 1 => "i" }

  def initialize(number)
    @number = number
  end

  def coerce(other)
    if Integer === other
      [ other, @number ]
    else
      [ Float(other), Float(@number) ]
    end
  end

  def <=>(n)
    @number <=> n
  end

  def -(n)
    Roman.new(@number - n)
  end 

  def to_s
    roman = ''
    ROMAN_NUMBERS.each do |value, letter|
      roman << letter * (@number / value)
      @number = @number % value
    end
    roman
  end
end
```

but I'm still failing this one

```
it "should support substraction" do
  (Roman.new(5) - Roman.new(3)).should == 2
  (Roman.new(4) - Roman.new(1)).should == 3
  (Roman.new(4) - 2).should == 2
  res = 6 - Roman.new(1)
  res.should == 5
  (res.kind_of? Roman).should be true
end
```

The problem is, that `res` is "kind of" `Fixnum`. How's that possible? How to make it pass the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `6 - Roman.new(1)` is the same as `6.-(Roman.new(1))` i.e. it is calling the built in subtraction method of `Fixnum`. Since `Fixnum` doesn't know about your `Roman` class, this calls your `coerce` method.

But you defined `coerce` to return a Fixnum in this case! The solution is to coerce the other operand, rather than `self`.

```
def coerce other
  [self.class.new(other), self]
end
```

But if you try this with your code, you'll get a stack error! That's because it's now coercing both operands into instances of `Roman` and it still doesn't know how to subtract them. You should redefine your subtraction method to handle those cases.

```
attr_reader :number
def - n
  return Roman.new(@number - n.number) if n.is_a? Roman
  Roman.new(@number - n)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and mainly for the explanation :)